# How can I remote control my Panasonic FZ100?

Tags: remote, usb, panasonic-lumix

I want to remote control my Panasonic DMC-FZ100 from my computer via USB. It does support PTP but [gPhoto2](http://www.gphoto.org/) says `Error (-6: 'Unsupported operation')`. [libptp](http://libptp.sourceforge.net/) also returns an error.

Do you know any other software to take still images with the FZ100?

Linux preferred but I have Windows in a VM, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, *that camera does not offer that feature via any software*. I did a little looking on gphoto2 forums, and in general it seems Panasonic's support for the PTP protocol used for USB communication is very rudimentary, on pretty much all of their compact camera models. So, basically: sorry, can't really be done.

Comment: I had never heard of gphoto2, cool.

Answer (score 0):

A recent version of [Phase One Capture One](http://tethertalk.com/2011/01/27/phase-one-capture-one-6-1-now-available-for-download/) lists your camera as available for tethered shooting (the ability to use the computer to control the camera).

While it isn't specifically for Linux, it will work for your camera.

Comment: Sorry for the delay; I'll try that and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not true. That list is for raw file support not tethered camera support. See p 5 & 6 of this release note. http://80.237.159.100/330a3505-0085-4247-a029-d396cc74c3c8/9c2aad0a-5c62-4fd0-916e-da4856d0fe13/Capture%20One%206.1%20Release%20Notes.pdf